# When to use Observable vs EventEmitter vs Dot Rule for change detection in angular2

Tags: angular

There are three methods I have seen to manage change detection in Angular2.

1. Observables

   ```
   @Injectable()
   export class TodosService {
       todos$: Observable<Array<Todo>>;
       private _todosObserver: any;
       private _dataStore: {
           todos: Array<Todo>
       };

       constructor(private _http: Http) {
           // Create Observable Stream to output our data
           this.todos$ = new Observable(observer => 
               this._todosObserver = observer).share();

           this._dataStore = { todos: [] };
       }
   }
   ```
2. EventEmitter.

   ```
   @Injectable()
   class NameService {
     name: any;
     nameChange: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
     constructor() {
       this.name = "Jack";
     }
     change(){
       this.name = "Jane";
       this.nameChange.emit(this.name);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Dot Rule

   ```
   export interface Info {
      name:string;
   }

   @Injectable()
   class NameService {
     info: Info = { name : "Jack" };
     change(){
       this.info.name = "Jane";
     }
   }
   ```

My question is, all three implementations can work when subscribing to watch changes in data. How do you decide when to use one instead of the other, and what are the drawbacks of each.

Comment: One disadvantage of dot rule: it is implicit rather than explicit.  So far, I prefer EventEmitter.

Comment: what is meant by dot rule?

Answer (score 37):

Let's try to give you some hints...

The main problem with the last approach is that it doesn't work with primitive types but only with references. So I wouldn't recommend it...

I think that `EventEmitter` / `Observable` is the right approach to implement and handle custom events. It's also linked to components themselves (`@Ouput`), bidirectional mapping in templates (syntax `[(...)]`) and the `async` pipe.

From the documentation, the `EventEmitter` uses `Observable` but provides an adapter to make it work as specified here: https://github.com/jhusain/observable-spec. After looking at the `EventEmitter` class of Angular2, it extends the `Subject` class. It's a bit more than a simple `Observable`. See this link for more details: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md

Regarding the creation of a custom observable, I would say: create your own observables only when you need something specific. Otherwise leverage the `EventEmitter` class. But there is a lot of things that you can do with the `EventEmitter` class and observable operators.

To conclude, on such a "simple" use case, things aren't so obvious but on more complex scenarios, `EventEmitter` / `Observable` allow to define an handling chain using operators. The classical sample is to update a list according to a value for an `input` (here `this.term` defined in the `ngModel` of the field):

```
this.term.valueChanges
     .debounceTime(400)
     .flatMap(term => this.dataService.getItems(term))
     .subscribe(items => this.items = items);
```

This great blog post from Christoph Burgdorf could give you some ideas about what observables can handle: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: As a side note: According to the [documentation for EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html) it should really only be used by components & directives; implying that it is not meant for services where Observables are preferred it would seem. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter) answer rather useful.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the above, we need to use Event Emitter for event binding between a child and parent component. Its better we avoid subscribing to it, as if and when it is deprecated in future, the code would need to be changed again. So better avoid using Event emitters except for event binding between a child and parent component. In other scenarios it best to use Observable's. Please check this link for details...
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3038-eventemitter-is-an-rxjs-observable-stream-in-angular-2-beta-6.htm#comments_47949