# Angular 2 Http Post sends two ajax calls instead of one

Tags: angular

Hi I am trying to wrap my head around the observable pattern implementation of angular and I seem to be having some sort of issues.Here is my code:

```
 import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import {GuidService} from './guid.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
    private http: Http;
    private guidService: GuidService;
    public ajaxStarted: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
    public ajaxCompleted: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter(); 

    constructor(http: Http, guidService: GuidService) {
        this.http = http;
        this.guidService = guidService;
    }

    public post(url: string, model: any): Observable<Response> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        //Create unique id for each ajax call
        let httpCallId = this.guidService.new();

        //Let Loading Box components that an ajax call has been triggered
        this.ajaxStarted.emit(httpCallId);

        let httpPost = this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(model), options);

        //Let Loadinc Box Component know that ajax call has been completed
        httpPost.subscribe(success => this.ajaxCompleted.emit(httpCallId), error => this.ajaxCompleted.emit(httpCallId));

        return httpPost;
    }

}
```

And this is my code that gets called on form submit:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'register',
    templateUrl: './app/account/components/register.view.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class RegisterComponent {
    private accountDataService: AccountDataService

    public registerViewModel: AccountViewModel.UserRegistrationViewModel;

    constructor(accountDataService: AccountDataService) {
        this.accountDataService = accountDataService;
        this.registerViewModel = <AccountViewModel.UserRegistrationViewModel>{};
    }

    public register() {
        this.accountDataService.register(this.registerViewModel).subscribe(x => {
            console.log(x);
        })
    }
}     

<form (ngSubmit)="register()" #userRegistrationForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" 
                       type="email" 
                       placeholder="Email Address"
                       [(ngModel)]="registerViewModel.userName" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" 
                       type="password" 
                       placeholder="Password"
                       [(ngModel)]="registerViewModel.password" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" 
                       type="password" 
                       placeholder="Password Confirmation"
                       [(ngModel)]="registerViewModel.confirmPassword" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" 
                        class="btn btn-fluid btn-primary"
                        [disabled]="!userRegistrationForm.form.valid">Register</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Now my problem is that when I click the submit button instead of one ajax calls to get sent to the server.I have checked this by putting a brakepoint on the server and two calls arive.

The register function gets called only oance on button clicked.

I have noticed that my problem is this line:

```
  httpPost.subscribe(success => this.ajaxCompleted.emit(httpCallId), error => this.ajaxCompleted.emit(httpCallId));
```

If I comment it only one ajax call gets sent to the server.

The way that I understand observables is that each subscribe gets triggered when ever the observable value changes.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

The issue apparently replicates also in the get calls. All the get calls in my app call ths function:

```
public get(url: string, model: any = {}): Observable<Response> {
    let httpCallId = this.guidService.new();

    this.ajaxStarted.emit(httpCallId);

    let httpGet = this.http.get(url, new RequestOptions({
        headers: this.getHttpHeaders(),
        search: this.createURLSearchParams(model)
    }));

    httpGet.subscribe(success => this.ajaxCompleted.emit(httpCallId), error => this.ajaxCompleted.emit(httpCallId));

    return httpGet;
}
```

Comment: Did you check if `register()` (`onSubmit` event handler) is only called once?

Comment: Yes it is called only oance... I just checked all my get calls which follow the same pattern they all fire twice

Comment: [Don't use EventEmitter in your services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter)

Comment: I think that the request is duplicated because you have (ngSubmit) and button type submit..so both do the request.. try with a button type button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that you subscribe twice to your POST observable because you subscribe once within the `post` method of the `HttpService` and return it. You probably subscribe again on this returned observable in another part of your application:

```
public post(url: string, model: any): Observable<Response> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    //Create unique id for each ajax call
    let httpCallId = this.guidService.new();

    //Let Loading Box components that an ajax call has been triggered
    this.ajaxStarted.emit(httpCallId);

    let httpPost = this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(model), options);

    //Let Loadinc Box Component know that ajax call has been completed
    httpPost.subscribe(success => { // <-------
        this.ajaxCompleted.emit(httpCallId);
    }, error => {
       this.ajaxCompleted.emit(httpCallId);
    });

    return httpPost;
}
```

Since observables are cold by default, the corresponding request will be executed twice (if subscribed twice).

Comment: Is there any other way to execute code without subscribing when the resul returns?

Comment: In you case observable is httPost

Comment: Hey Thierry ! ... so do you mean that the code sample given on angualr 2 docs is wrong is some way ... https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#update  ....... Because I am getting same problem on all post request and not on Get request ... I also didnt got observable.do things - I searched on net and got a sample code - but that also didnt worked for me. Can you please post a working sample or what shall I do ?? I am using Angular 2.0.0-rc.1 - let me know if you recommend me update to latest version immediately or no - thank you

Comment: BDW i forgot to say - that I took all the code in one place and subscribed it once and tried it but it still sends two ajax request ... please do help - TY