# How to unsubscribe from EventEmitter in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, rxjs, eventemitter

```
export declare class EventEmitter<T> extends Subject<T> {
    /**
     * Creates an instance of [EventEmitter], which depending on [isAsync],
     * delivers events synchronously or asynchronously.
     */
    constructor(isAsync?: boolean);
    emit(value: T): void;
    /**
     * @deprecated - use .emit(value) instead
     */
    next(value: any): void;
    subscribe(generatorOrNext?: any, error?: any, complete?: any): any;
}
```

In Official Angular 2 Typescript definition, seems it has no way to mute or unsubscribe from EventEmitter.

I got callback over time as pages use the same EventEmitter

Comment: Show how you're using the event emitter instead

Answer (score 56, accepted):

EventEmitter extends Subject. When you subscribe to a subject you get a `Subscription` which you can later use to unsubscribe.

```
someOutput:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
...
this.subscription = someOutput.subscribe(...);
...
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```

**Hint**
Don't use `EventEmitter` for anything else but `@Output()`s. Angular doesn't guarantee that `EventEmitter` will keep extending `Subject` or even work similar to a `Subject` in the future.

Comment: Hey I believe your hint is in effect now. I believe it's now impossible to unsubscribe from the returned value, can you confirm?

Comment: It still extends Subject in v5.x so this will still work - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.1/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L10-L116

Answer (score 13):

Because EventEmitters should [only be used to emit events from components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter), and hence they should not be subscribed to, there is no need for Angular to provide a means to unsubscribe.

If you are not using an output property in a component, use an Observable or a Subject instead of an EventEmitter.

Maybe they should change the name to OutputPropertyEmitter.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I use Observable or Subject in this use case?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Günter Zöchbauer you can unsubscribe from EventEmitter as following:

```
someOutput: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
...
this.subscription = someOutput.subscribe(...);
...
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Since Angular says you should not use EventEmitter for things other than @Output (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter) post):

> Quoting a comment from Rob Wormald
>
> > [...] EventEmitter is really an Angular abstraction, and should be
> > used pretty much only for emitting custom Events in components.
> > Otherwise, just use Rx as if it was any other library.
>
> This is stated really clear in EventEmitter's documentation.
>
> > Use by directives and components to emit custom Events.

Instead you should be using the Rxjs Subject. EventEmitter extends the Rxjs Subject which means you can pretty much use it in the same way. Although you have to use the **"subject.next()" function instead of "eventEmitter.emit()"**, subscribe and unsubscribe work the same.

```
someOutput: EventEmitter = new Subject();
...
this.subscription = someOutput.subscribe(...);
...
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```