# Immediately unsubscribing from RxJS Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

Could anyone shed some light on how I would immediately unsubscribe from an `RxJS` subscription? The observable is from Angular 2 `EventEmitter`. When I recieve the event, I want to cancel the subscription. The issue here is cancelling the subscription **within** the function block. I have a feeling that this is the wrong approach:

```js
this.subscription = observable.subscribe(result => {
    // do something
    // **unsubscribe**
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unsubscribe from EventEmitter in Angular 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494509/how-to-unsubscribe-from-eventemitter-in-angular-2)

Comment: take(1) seems to be a better option compared to first()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345969/angular-2-using-rxjs-take1-vs-first

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
observable.first().subscribe(....)
```

will end the subscription after the first event.

**Update for RxJs 6+**

```
observable.pipe(first()).subscribe(....)
```

Comment: This is the approach I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: There are other similar operators like `.take(1)` or `.skip(5).take(1)` to get the 6th event only.

Comment: So if I use `take` or `first` I won't be getting any emission in the future, is it right? Does it apply to [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html) as well?

Comment: Not sure what you expext. If you say you want the first or take 5 then that is what you get. Why would you expect something else?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I am learning Observables and trying to understand its logic. It makes sense what you've said. But I thought that I could take 5, do something with them and maybe in the future get new updates/new values.

Comment: I see. No, this is not how it works. You'd need to count yourself in `subscribe` or whatever method you use process events and count yourself and skip using `if(...)` if it is a position you do not care of.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @GünterZöchbauer