# Do I need to unsubsribe a subscription of a stream that has completed?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

I've seen different sources that seem to contradict on the matter, or maybe there's something I haven't understood.

For example, I could get a stream from an async request that returns a promise and then combine it with the latest values of other streams and subscribe to it to perform some action with the results. The stream will only emit once, so I can close it after the first emission.

If I create a stream, map a first() operator so that it completes after the first emitted value, and subscribe to it, do I need to unsubscribe explicitly to avoid memory leaks, or will the completion of the stream "unsubscribe" automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need to unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks. If you don't want to unsubscribe use `toPromise()` - this will convert observable to promise that you don't need to unsubscirbe.

Comment: Is this response not true, then ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019177/immediately-unsubscribing-from-rxjs-observable

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is good to unsubscribe as it will reduce your stack