# What happened with subscription if subject was destroyed in angular 2+?

Tags: angular, observable, subscription, unsubscribe

**UPDATE more details about observable usage**

*I've need service because checkboxcell component can't use @Output() property.*
This happened becaues of wrong usage with ag-grid api - renderer component was used as editor. It can't be corrected at this moment.

```
@Component({
    ...
    template: `<mat-checkbox (change)="onChanged($event)"></mat-checkbox>`
})
export class CheckboxCellComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
    ...
    //each component that use checkboxcell provide own instance of PermissionChange
    constructor(private permissionChange: PermissionChange) {

    }
    public onChanged({ checked }): void {
         //use observable
         this.permissionChange.changeEvent.next();
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL question**

I have a simple service

```
export class PermissionChange {
    public changeEvent: Subject<void>;
    constructor() {
        this.changeEvent = new Subject<void>();
    }
}
```

And component, that use the service:

```
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [PermissionChange]
})
export class ...Component implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private permissionChange: PermissionChange,
    ) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        //subscription
        this.permissionChange.changeEvent.subscribe(() => {...});
    }
}
```

`PermisionChange` is personal provider for this component => instance of `PermisionChange` will be destroyed in the moment when component will be destroyed => `changeEvent` observable will be destroyed too. So maybe there is no need to unsubscribe, maybe subscribtion will be destroyed too? But I don't know how to check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unsubscribe from EventEmitter in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494509/how-to-unsubscribe-from-eventemitter-in-angular-2)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494509/how-to-unsubscribe-from-eventemitter-in-angular-2 . Look espacially on the second answer. EventEmitter should be used in component only. In a Injectable you should use plain Observables

Comment: @PierreMallet I've used the observable and edited the question.

Comment: What is the actual code of the service? It matters. How is the observable really created, and when does it emit events?

Comment: But you added an observable that never emit a data.. its hard to say of you need to unsubscribe. If your changeEvent in not a Subject ( if it complete after first emition you dont need to unsubscribe ). But as JB NIzet says, we cant help you without much details on implementation

Comment: @PierreMallet this is the actual code of the service, also I've provided more details

Comment: @JBNizet  this is the actual code of the service, also I've provided more details

Comment: Observable doesn't have a next() method. This code wouldn't compile.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right, in real code it still EventEmitter :) So subject is what I need according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494509/how-to-unsubscribe-from-eventemitter-in-angular-2 , question is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to unsubscribe in this case: the parent component, the child components and the service instance will all be destroyed and be eligible to garbage collection when the parent component is destroyed.

Nothing live will keep a reference to the Subject in the service, and it will thus be eligible to GC, too.

Comment: I've just read more about subject, so subscription - is disposable resource. When I've written changeEvent.subscribe() - resources were alloced. I not sure that destroying the changeEvent object lead to subscription's dispose. Maybe you know how to check it?

Comment: Yes, because resources were allocated not somewhere in space but in the subject instance, so when subject was destroyed all resources were disposed too.