# How to import component into another root component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to import component from one file another root component file.
it give error as ..

> zone.js:484 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   'courses' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'courses' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'courses' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("
>
> ## My First Angular 2 App
>
> [ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@0:31 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
>   'courses' is not a known element:

My app.component.ts be like [root component file]

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><courses></courses>',
  directives:[CoursesComponent],
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

and my courses.component.ts be ;

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'courses',
  template: '<h1>courses</h1>'
})
export class CoursesComponent { }
```

while importing courses component from courses.component.ts file inside app.component i am not able declare directive inside `@Component{}`

`directives:[CoursesComponent]` giving error to me

Please advise solution over it.

Comment: Which Angular2 version are you using?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You should declare it with **`declarations array(meta property) of @NgModule`** as shown below (`RC5 and later`),

```ts
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,CoursesComponent],  //<----here
  providers:    [],      
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Answer (score 43):

For Angular RC5 and RC6 you have to declare component in the module metadata decorator's `declarations` key, so add `CoursesComponent` in your main module `declarations` as **below and remove `directives` from `AppComponent` metadata.**

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CoursesComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 14):

**Angular RC5 & RC6**

If you are getting the above mentioned error in your Jasmine tests, it is most likely because you have to declare the unrenderable component in your `TestBed.configureTestingModule({})`.

The TestBed configures and initializes an environment for unit testing and provides methods for mocking/creating/injecting components and services in unit tests.

If you don't declare the component before your unit tests are executed, Angular will not know what `<courses></courses>` is in your template file.

**Here is an example:**

```ts
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {AppComponent} from "../app.component";
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component';

describe('CoursesComponent', () => {
  let component: CoursesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CoursesComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CoursesComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule
        // If you have any other imports add them here
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CoursesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: This is the anwser what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Saved my life. Thanks. I've been spoiled by React/Jest/Enzyme, which automates away this kind of tedium.

Answer (score 9):

above answers In simple words, 
you have to register under `@NgModule`'s

```ts
declarations: [
    AppComponent, YourNewComponentHere
  ]
```

of `app.module.ts`

do not forget to `import` that component.