# Unable to use child component in a parent component in Angular2

Tags: angular, components, angular2-components

I am trying to use the child component inside the main component, app.component using the selector inside the template of the main component. However it is not working.

child.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'child-component',
templateUrl: `<p>Child Component</p>`
})
export class ChildComponent  {  }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent} from './child.component';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<h1>Hello Angular!</h1>
<child-component>    </child-component>       `
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

I did the declaration in the modules as below for the ChildComponent

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChildComponent} from './child.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule],
declarations: [AppComponent,ChildComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

The solution mentioned at [How to import component into another root component in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410417/how-to-import-component-into-another-root-component-in-angular-2) does not works.

Please help with a resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had typo inside `child-component` meta options.

```
templateUrl: `<p>Child Component</p>`
```

should be

```
template: `<p>Child Component</p>`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It is working now like magic. Please let me know how do I debug it. I was not successful in tracing it from the terminal/console.

Comment: Error message inside a browser console are explanatory, you should look at them first