# using Knockout components in angularjs SPA

Tags: angular, knockout.js, single-page-application, code-reuse

I am using angularjs for our SPA, however we have some external components which are using knockout, that we want to load in our SPA. I understand it is possible to do the same in angular, but not sure about the best way to achive this functionality.

Could you please five me some pointers regarding the same or any sample implementation?

Thanks
Raghu

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question, I believe they are trying to achieve the same thing as you:

[How to import component into another root component in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410417/how-to-import-component-into-another-root-component-in-angular-2)