# Having Issues with Angular Components

Tags: angular, components, angular-cli

I understand that this is an existing thread here: [How to import component into another root component in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410417/how-to-import-component-into-another-root-component-in-angular-2), however this does not solve my problem.

I have the same problem here.

I'm trying to figure out Angular-Cli - successfully created a new project, and added component. All the tips found in the post above are automatically implemented.

When try using the component as represented (adding a <superman></superman>) to the template,  I get this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'superman' is not a known element:
1. If 'superman' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<h1>
  {{title}}
  [ERROR ->]<superman></superman>
</h1>
"):
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import component into another root component in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410417/how-to-import-component-into-another-root-component-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to register that component in a module. Look at the top answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410417/how-to-import-component-into-another-root-component-in-angular-2)

e.g.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, SupermanComponent],  //<----here
  providers:    [],      
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent]
})
```

And make sure the selector of SupermanComponent is superman

e.g.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'superman',
  template: '...'
  ...
})
export class SupermanComponent { ...
```

Comment: Can the selector just be "SupermanComponent" if I use <SupermanComponent></SupermanComponent>? a framework convention? This is super annoying to me to call things so many things :)