# ng test angular 5 fails

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to execute tests on my angular 5 app using Karma ,but I have basicly the same error for like 10 components which is : 
AccountsComponent should create

> Failed: Template parse errors: 'app-wizard-cmp-edit' is not a known
>   element:
>   1. If 'app-wizard-cmp-edit' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-wizard-cmp-edit' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("
>         
>         
>           [ERROR ->]
>         
>        "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AccountsComponent.html@51:8

when I searched for solution online like this [How to import component into another root component in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410417/how-to-import-component-into-another-root-component-in-angular-2)
it did not solve my problem 
Above is the imports in my Accounts Module :

```
    @NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(AccountsRoutes),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NouisliderModule,
        TagInputModule,
        MaterialModule, SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [AccountsComponent, WizardComponent],
    exports: [WizardComponent]
    , providers: [AccountslistService],

})
export class AccountsModule {
}
```

and here is the ngModule :

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
        MaterialModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        SidebarModule,
        NavbarModule,
        FooterModule,
        FixedpluginModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AdminLayoutComponent,
        AuthLayoutComponent,
        AccountsComponent

    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    , providers: [AuthGuard, AuthenticationService, ChatAlertsService, Configuration]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I am really stuck coz I don't know why the test fails however the app is working fine when I build it

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the test cases for any one component that fails.
Most probably you don't have the current component or the child component in the declarations of ConfigureTestingModule function.

Comment: I just followed the steps that I found on official guide online on how to Test angular apps

Answer (score 0):

You can add `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]`  to your test component configuration, which will simply ignore the errors related to `child component` tags.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
      // other stuff
})
```

**But be careful when you use this, as it might hide any other errors as well causing difficulty in debugging the failing test cases.**