# How to link angular material navigation bar HTML with project componet?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am working on an Angular project for the first time. Inside my project I created an angular material navigation bar using ng generate. I was able to link the bar with my project easily but now I am having trouble using the methods inside my project in my toolbar. I want to implement functions which are in my main component into the toolbar .html page. How should I go about this ? I have included a picture of my project files:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you need to declare and then import the component.
Please check this answer: [import-component-into-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410417/how-to-import-component-into-another-root-component-in-angular-2)
There are several answers regarding angular version, so please be aware of that.