# Simple way to use dropzone with Angular 2

Tags: angular, dropzone.js

I'm a little bit lost with SystemJS and NGModules (I just follow instructions and get it working).

In the case of [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), I've tried to add dropzone.js/css as a script in my `head` and added the class `dropzone` in my form but it doesn't work, the dropzone is not created...

Anyone can show me how to implement Dropzone in Angular 2 (final version)?

Comment: have I solved your issue?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little Component i wrapped Dropzone.js in:

first run

> npm install --save dropzone

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Output } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/directives';

let Dropzone = require('../../../node_modules/dropzone/dist/dropzone-amd-module');

@Component({
  selector: 'hsr-dropzone',
  templateUrl: 'dropzone.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['dropzone.component.scss']
})
export class DropzoneComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output() filesUploading: EventEmitter<File[]> = new EventEmitter<File[]>();
  // TODO: acceptedFiles option as input

  dropzone;

  constructor() {
  }

  get fileDropped(): boolean {
    if (this.dropzone) {
      return this.dropzone.files.length > 0;
    }
    return false;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dropzone = new Dropzone('div#my_dropzone', {
      url: (files) => {
        this.filesUploading.emit(files);
      },
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      uploadMultiple: true,
      parallelUploads: 20,
      hiddenInputContainer: '#dropzone-drop-area',
      dictDefaultMessage: '',
      maxFiles: 20,
      acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
      clickable: '#dropzone-drop-area',
      previewsContainer: '#dropzone-drop-area',
      previewTemplate: `
<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
  <div class="dz-details">
    <img data-dz-thumbnail/>
  </div>
</div>
`
    });
    this.dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    this.dropzone.on('addedfile', (file) => {
      /*file.previewElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
       this.dropzone.removeFile(file);
       });*/
    });
    this.dropzone.on('completemultiple', (files) => {
      this.dropzone.removeAllFiles();
    });
    // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
    this.dropzone.on('sendingmultiple', () => {
      console.log('sending!!!!!!!');
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dropzone.disable();
  }

  upload() {
    this.dropzone.processQueue();
  }
}
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<div class="dropzone-container" id="my_dropzone">
  <div id="dropzone-drop-area" class="dropzone-drop-area">
    <div *ngIf="!fileDropped" class="centered noselect clickthrough">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button md-raised-button style="float: right;" *ngIf="fileDropped" (click)="upload()">
  <i class="fa fa-upload fa-lg"></i>
</button>
```

STYLES:

```
.dropzone-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.dropzone-drop-area {
  border: dashed 3px grey;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 120px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  &:hover {
    color: darkorange;
    border-color: darkorange;
  }
}
```

I really hope that helps.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the event emitter stating that traceur.js and jquery are required. I also looked up usage for event emitter and what you have is not recommended:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter

Answer (score 2):

If you're not bound to `dropzone.js` I might suggest the following library to you.

I've written a highly customizable Angular component which implements the correct Drag'n'Drop behavior so I don't need to copy it over and over again. It returns a list of the dropped files as an output event.
This can be found [here](https://github.com/peterfreeman/ngx-dropzone).

After you imported the module you have access to the component:

```
<ngx-dropzone [multiple]="false" [maxFileSize]="2000"></ngx-dropzone>
```

You have some options to set and it comes with a decent default styling (screenshots can be found in the GitHub repo). If you want to, you can even take your own `div` container with your custom styles and hover effects and put it in the dropzone. Details on this can be found in the API description.

```
<ngx-dropzone [customContent]="customDropzone" (filesDropped)="onFilesDropped($event)">
<ng-template #customDropzone>
    <div class="custom-dropzone">
        This is my custom content
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

might I suggest this instead :

https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper

`let Dropzone = require` is no longer deemed cannon in Angular 2+ (we're up to 5 and nearly version 6 now)

Answer (score 1):

Steps to work [Dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) with Angular 6 (angular version: 6.1.8)

**1.** Create angular project using angular CLI and download *dropzone dist folder* from dropzonejs.com site.

**2.** Put *dropzone.css* (from downloaded dist folder) in projects *../src/assets/css* folder (if not exists, then create) and import it in *styles.css* file like following

```
styles.css
----------

@import "../src/assets/css/dropzone.css";
```

**3.** Put *dropzone.js* (from downloaded dist folder) file in projects *../src/assets/js* folder (if not exists, then create) and put the following value in the scripts option of *angular.json* file:

```
angular.json
------------

    "scripts": [
        "src/assets/js/lib/dropzone.js"
    ]
```

**4.** Now, in you component ts file (for example, app.component.ts), define your Dropzone and its options like the following way:

```
app.component.ts
----------------

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    declare var Dropzone: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      ngOnInit(): void {

        Dropzone.options.pdfDropzone = {
          paramName: 'file',
          maxFilesize: 5, // MB
          uploadMultiple: true,
          autoProcessQueue: true,
          init: function () {
              this.on('addedfile', function (file) {
                  const removeButton = Dropzone.createElement('<button class=\'btn btn-sm btn-block\'>Remove file</button>');
                  const _this = this;
                  removeButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      e.stopPropagation();
                      _this.removeFile(file);
                  });

                  file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
              });
          }
      };
      }
    }
```

**5.** Now, add the following div in the html file:

```
app.component.html
------------------

    <div>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/api/upload/file"
              class="dropzone dz-clickable"
              id="pdf-dropzone">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Action attribute of form element is the url where dropzone will upload the file.

**It works for me. Cheers!!**