# Angular 2 Detect changes from another service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an AuthService, that contains actual user data and method for login.
If I click on 'Login button', I call my AuthService to get new user data from server and rewrite 'this.user' value;

So, in a header, I show the username.

Question:
How my HeaderComponent can know, that this.user in the AuthService is changed ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can expose an Observable on your `AuthService`. 
Then you will be able to subscribe to this stream in your `HeaderComponent`. 
You can use the `EventEmitter` class which extends the RxJS Subject class. Moreover, you can use a TypeScript setter to automatically trigger the event for changes.
So, your code should look like :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private _user: any;
    userStream: EventEmitter<any>;


    constructor() {
      this.userStream = new EventEmitter();
    }

    //code ...

    getUserData() {
      //call our setter
      this.user = newData;
    }

    set user(newValue) {
      this._user = newValue;
      //set user data and emit a value in the userStream
      this.userStream.emit(newValue);
    }
}
```

Then you can use your service in your component :

```
@Component({...})
export class HeaderComponent {
    currentUser: any;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        //subscribe to the stream to be notified when user data has changed
        authService.userStream.subscribe((newUser) => { this.currentUser = newUser; });
    }
}
```

So you will be able to listen change on your user data.

Comment: FYI, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36076701/6680611) suggests that an Angular 2 `EventEmitter` should not be used in that manner. You could just use an RxJS `Subject` instead.