# Input as an EventEmitter in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have used Input to component as Event Emitter. I have many child components (few with Event Emitter as Input).
Is components input which is an Event Emitter is good practice?
If possible please suggest any document.

Comment: can you explain more or share your code sample. it's not clear. Main thing is if you want to pass information from child to parent, you should use Event emmitor.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: I'd suggest that using an `EventEmitter` as an input it is not best practice, as it would involve having to manually subscribe to an `EventEmitter`. You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36076701/6680611) useful in explaining the proper use of `EventEmitter`.