# Angular 2 subscribing to service event

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here is my code:

`App.component`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.favoritesServ.addFavoriteEvent
      .subscribe(data => this.name = data)
}
```

`Service`

```
addFavoriteEvent = new EventEmitter();
pushData(value) {
  this.addFavoriteEvent.emit(value)
}
```

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Comment: What im i doing wrong as far as subscribing

Comment: Please give a [mcve] that actually explains the problem you're having. Right now you don't even tell us why you think something's wrong.

Comment: It's not recommended for `EventEmitter` to be used for that purpose. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36076701/6680611

Answer (score -2):

Use an Observable or Promise for your purpose.

Also, according to Angular2 style guide, don't abbreviate class names or properties.

A very simple example would be:

**Service:**

```
private observer; //an observer that 'emits' values to the Observable 
addFavoriteEvent : Observable<any> = new Observable<any>(observer => this.observer = observer); 
//create an instance of an Observable and assign the created observer to our local observer for easy re-usage.


pushData(value) {

  this.observer.next(value);
}
```

Your component may stay unchanged.

Comment: no cigar, past the transpile but when I try to invoke pushData i get:
Cannot read property 'next' of undefined

Comment: Well then your data is not assigned in an earlier step

Comment: when i console.log value when the service is called I have the data i want