# How to update value inside ionic 2 side menu

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

How to "transfer" date from page into `side-menu` in Ionic2, i.e -
Having `app.page.html` like following:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">

    <ion-content class="menu-left">
        <!-- User profile -->
        <div text-center padding-top padding-bottom class="primary-bg menu-left">
            <a menuClose>
                <h4 light>{{userName}}</h4>
            </a>
        </div>

        <ion-list class="list-full-border">
            <button ion-item menuClose *ngFor="let page of pages" (click)="openPage(page)">
        <ion-icon item-left name="{{ page.icon }}"></ion-icon>
        {{ page.title }}
        <ion-badge color="danger" item-right *ngIf="page.count">{{ page.count }}</ion-badge>
      </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

how to update `userName` value upon the action in the page upon the data gotten from `facebookLogin.page` ?

`facebookLogin.page.ts`:

```
...
fbLogin() {
    Facebook.login(["public_profile", "email"])
      .then((resp: FacebookLoginResponse) => {

        if (resp.status === "connected") {
          Facebook.api("/me", ["public_profile", "email"])
            .then(res => {
             this.userName = res.name
              this.login({name: this.userName})
            })
        ...
      );
  }

 login(params) {
    this.nav.setRoot(HomePage, params);
  }
...
```

(so, how would I import the `userName` which I get after login with facebook into `ion-sideMenu` in `app.html`; how I could make **EventEmmiter**, **service**/**observe** for changes in app.html's ion-menu ... some other way?)

Comment: What is `facebookLogin.page`? Show some code.

Comment: Add it to the post, please

Comment: I don't understand why you request another way instead of observing for changes? That's the best way in my opinion, makes it easier to log out and login with different socialmedia and different pages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### **ionic2 - using Events**

Check out the Events [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/)

They allow you to 'publish' an action from any page, and subscribe to it in another page to retrieve the value. Your scenario would look a bit like this.

Import (both on `Facebooklogin.component` and `app.component`)

`import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';` and in your constructor `constructor(public events: Events)`

Then, whenever you change your `userName` (f.e. in the handler of the facebook login) publish the value like this.

```
fbLogin() {
    Facebook.login(["public_profile", "email"])
      .then((resp: FacebookLoginResponse) => {

        if (resp.status === "connected") {
          Facebook.api("/me", ["public_profile", "email"])
            .then(res => {
             this.userName = res.name
             // publish the username change to the events
             this.events.publish('username:changed', this.userName);
              this.login({name: this.userName})
            })
        //...
      );
  }
```

And subscribe to any publishes being made in your `app.component`

```
userName: string;

constructor(events: Events) {
   this.userName = "not logged in";

   events.subscribe('username:changed', username => {
      if(username !== undefined && username !== ""){
        this.userName = username;
      }
   }) //... 
}
```

---

### **angular2** - using `EventEmitter`

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

public userChanged = new EventEmitter();

fbLogin() {
        Facebook.login(["public_profile", "email"])
          .then((resp: FacebookLoginResponse) => {

            if (resp.status === "connected") {
              Facebook.api("/me", ["public_profile", "email"])
                .then(res => {
                 this.userName = res.name
                 // publish the username change to the events
                 this.userChanged.emit(this.userName);
                 this.login({name: this.userName})
                })
            ...
          );
      }
```

App.component

```
import { FacebookLogin } from '../pages/facebook/facebook.component';

public userName;

constructor(fb: FacebookLogin){

    this.userName = "";
    //subscribe to the page's EventEmitter
    this.fb.userChanged.subscribe(username => {
       this.userName = username;
    });
}
```

OR use the `EventEmitter` as an `Output` as described in this S.O. answer: [What is the proper use of an EventEmitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter)

Comment: okay, and would you be so cool to propose example using just Angular2 features - services, eventEmmiters... (as ion Events works fine) :) tnks

Comment: Yes ofcourse, give me a minute, EventEmitter works as well

Comment: You could definitely do the same with a Service inbetween to make sure you're having the same object. (not sure how this works in angular with page objects) but the EventEmitter would still be in the service I believe