# Angular 2 ionic 2, calling a child component undefined

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a global footer in my ionic app, the way I did it is this way. I added the selector component inside the ion-nav and it is working well. My footer is showing in every page.

in the **app.html**

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false">

</ion-nav>
<call-footer #CallChild></call-footer>
```

However, in one the pages, I want to have control of the footer and I may hide it or change the variables inside it. In my footer component i have a function called 'test' and in one of the pages('calls') I am trying this.

**calls.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

import { oncallpage } from '../calls/oncall/oncall';
import { callfooter } from '../../components/callfooter/callfooter.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-calls',
    templateUrl: 'calls.html'
})
export class callspage implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('CallChild') child;


    constructor() { }


      ngAfterViewInit() {
         this.child.test(); //error
  }
```

However I am getting ***"Cannot read property 'test' of undefined"***

I am not sure if there is a syntax error or I am missing some idea. How can I solve this case?

Comment: What does your calls.html looks like?

Comment: i edited. this is the one calls.html

Comment: I don't see the calls.html. There's an app.html

Comment: the code below is the calls.html. maybe the edit still didn't refresh

Comment: That's not the html. It is the ts file

Comment: oh its almost empty till now. But I have a button in the header, when I call it I want to execute a function in the footer component. I put the code

Comment: Ok so where is `#CallChild` inside your calls.html?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143753/discussion-between-missak-boyajian-and-echonax).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@ViewChild` returns an `ElementRef`. You can't invoke a function like that.

A workaround would be to use ionic's `Events` [(docs)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/)

Change your function to:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.events.publish("child:test");
}
```

And in your child page:

```
constructor(events: Events) {
  events.subscribe("child:test", ()=> {
     this.test();
  });
}

test() { console.log("test called"); }
```

Also for a more detailed explanation, refer to my answer here [How to update value inside ionic 2 side menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280022/how-to-update-value-inside-ionic-2-side-menu/41280219#41280219)

Comment: Hi, follow up question. I am trying something like this

//callspage
this.events.publish("child:initializefooter",this);


//footer
events.subscribe("child:initializefooter", (page) => { 
this.ModalExitCall = page;
this.ModalExitCall.present(); //opens the model. Getting Error:
//No component factory found for [object Object]

})
Is there a way to cast the input parameter as component ?

Comment: On my phone at the moment but look into Angular's `output` arguments. You'll be able to call a function with them