# Angular 2 pass data between two components from the same tree level?

Tags: angular

Given two angular 2 components :

- ListItemsComponent.
- ShowItemComponent.

When user selects an item from `ListItemComponent` he must be redirected to `ShowItemComponent` by receiving **selected item object**.

Knowing that both components are present in the same tree level.

What is the best way to past object item from `listItemsComponent` to `ShowItemComponent` ?

Comment: return to parent ? and inject ?

Comment: You can use "EventEmitter" in data service...Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter

Comment: isn't there a direct way to communicate data without passing by parent as intermediate ?

Comment: please add you design screen images. You redirect component using route?

Comment: yes I redirect using route, about screen sorry I wont it's confidential

Comment: It's all explained here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: yes u cant comunnicate components withouts parent, in other hand u can inject @viewChild from parent to childs component ;) if u dont want return values to parent ;)

Comment: isn't there a way to comunicate object using router like we did on angular 1.x

Comment: @user2080105 short simple answer: No. It's not possible to communicate with router. Only case is to stringify it and pass it as route parameter, but then that would show in your url.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Router.navigate` and give it the path of other component with the item id 
in ListItemComponent
in constructor declare the Route  `constructor( private _router: Router)`

```
 this._router.navigate(['..../ShowItemComponent', {itemId:itemId}])
```

and in the ShowItemComponent put `ActivatedRoute`

```
constructor(private _activateRoute: ActivatedRoute){

      this._activateRoute.params.subscribe(
          (param: any) => {
            let itemId = param['itemId'];
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't want to http request the same item twice (performance issue).