# Angular 2: event broadcast service

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create event broadcast service.

Here is basic concept what I would like to achieve:

```
export enum Event {
   EVENT_A,
   EVENT_B, ...
}


@Injectable()
export class BroadcastService {

     private broadcastSubject: Subject<Event> = new Subject<Event>();

     public next(event: Event): void {
         return this.broadcastSubject.next(event);
     }

     public subscribe(event: Event, componentCall: Function): void {
         this.broadcastSubject.subscribe(
             eventValue => {
                if(event === eventValue) {
                  componentCall(); // not possible to call component's method like this
                } 
             }
        );
   }
}
```

I know I can't call component's method from service like this. I have to return observable somehow and call it from component. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Thanks for any advice.

---

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to [AngularFrance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1153681/angularfrance), here is solution for the BroadcastService:

```
@Injectable()
export class BroadcastService {

  private broadcastSubject: BehaviorSubject<Event> = new BehaviorSubject<Event>(0);

  public next(event: Event): void {
     return this.broadcastSubject.next(event);
  }

  public subject(event: Event): Observable<Event> {
     return this.broadcastSubject.asObservable().filter(e => e === event);
  }

}
```

Comment: typescript does not support callback function you cannot do it that way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return the observable from `BroadcastService` (NB. A `Subject` is an `Observable`):

```ts
@Injectable()
export class BroadcastService {

     private event: Subject<Event> = new Subject<Event>();

     public next(event: Event): void {
       return this.event.next(event);
     }

     public getEvents(event: Event): Observable<Event> {
       // DO NOT SUBSCRIBE HERE. Return the observable.
       return this.event.asObservable()
         // Only keep events matching the given `event` param
         .filter(e => e == event);
     }
}
```

Then subscribe to the returned observable from a component:

```ts
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(bcservice: BroadcastService) {
    // Subscribe here.
    bcservice.getEvents(event).subscribe(eventValue => {
      this.someMethod();
    });
  }

  someMethod() { }

}
```

NOTE: If you only ever want a specific type of events in the stream, it might be more optimal to filter out unwanted events **before** adding them to the stream (in the `next()` method) as opposed to when returning the stream.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. 

But what I would like to achieve is that the
 /* test eventValue */ will be in BroadcastService, otherwise there is no point of wrapping Subject into BroadcastService.

Comment: You're saying you only want to call your method for certain events?

Comment: Yes, I would like to subscribe just for one event: subscribe(event: Event, ...).

Comment: Then I suggest you pass a param to `getEvents()` (like you did in your original code) and use that param to filter the observable with the `.filter()` operator. See my updated answer.

Comment: Well this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using events form Angular 2: 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html

Or even better Rx: 
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-introduction-to-reactive-extensions-rxjs-a86a7430a61f#.dsaecx6sc

Here you also have a sample: 
https://github.com/ng-book/angular2-rxjs-chat

Comment: Well it doesn't seem like good idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter