# Using event emitter in Angular2 to share data between service and component

Tags: angular, angular2-services, eventemitter

I have an angular2 application in which I have a login page. After login, I would like to display the user name in the header component.

```js
    @Output() getUserName = new EventEmitter();
```

In the authenticate method of service

```js
authenticate(loginRequest)  {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let authenticateResp = this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/authenticate", JSON.stringify(loginRequest), options).map(result => result.json());
    authenticateResp.subscribe((authenticate => {
        this.getUserName.emit("My Name");
    }));    

    return authenticateResp; 
}
```

In the header component in constructor

```js
@Component({
 .....
 providers:[LoginService]
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  userName : string;
  constructor(private loginService : LoginService) { 

      loginService.getUserName.subscribe(authenticated => this.setName(authenticated));
  }

  setName(authenticated) {
    this.userName = authenticated;
  }

}
```

When I debug, I can see the event emitting code getting executed, but the code in subscribe in the component is not called. What am I doing wrong here?

Appreciate any help

Comment: I suggest you to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter, you shouldn't use `@Output` in your services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Output()` and `EventEmitter` are not meant to be used inside a service, as they are [designed for inter-component communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter).

`EventEmitter` is (for now) a subclass of `Subject`, a standard `Subject`, will not keep the latest emitted value in memory, so if a value is emitted while there is no subscriber, the value just got ignored.

A `ReplaySubject` will repeat the last emitted value to any new subscriber.

**Notes**:

- it is a good practice to only expose `Observable` instead of `Subject`.
- You don't want to subscribe to `authenticateResp` inside your `authenticate` method and return `authenticateResp` at the same time as this will trigger the request twice if you subscribe to the returned value. You should use the `do()` operator, return the observable and subscribe where you need that data.

```js
private _userName = new ReplaySubject<string>();

userName=this._userName.asObservable();

authenticate(loginRequest)  {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/authenticate", JSON.stringify(loginRequest), options)
        .map(result => result.json())
        .do((authenticate => this._userName.next("My Name")));    
}
```

and inside your component :

```js
loginService.userName.subscribe(authenticated => this.setName(authenticated));
```

Comment: I tried this, still the method in subscribe in the component is not being executed

Comment: is `authenticate` called somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, authenticate service is called from a component. Its being executed without any issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce in plunkr ?

Comment: @ConfusionPrevails how do you know the method in subscribe is not called?

Comment: I have put logs in the method executed in subscribe i.e, in setName, they are not printed. Neither is the value of the variable updated.

Comment: @n00dl3
I have added the code to plunkr. I haven't used plunkr before, so not sure if this is the right way. Thank you for the help.plnkr.co/edit/CpnQlf0CkkaiYvOk0h1y?p=preview

Comment: I realized my mistake. I had added LoginService as provider in Header component as well as LoginComponent. After I moved this to app.module, I am getting the right value in subscribe.