# Angular 2 two-way binding between components via observable in service

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services, angular2-observables

I would like to store a value in a service which any component can watch and change, and when any component changes the value, all other components watching the value will be updated.

After some research, i have found this solution that makes sense to me but does not work.

https://plnkr.co/edit/mlVfASdAw1vbpJRhGFov?p=preview

Service

```
        export class Service {
            value: string;
            subject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
            setValue(value: string): void {
                this.subject.next(value);
            }
            getObservable(): Observable<string> {
                return this.subject.asObservable();
            }
        }
```

Component 1

```
        @Component({
            selector: 'comp-1',
            template: `
                <div>
                Value in component 1: {{value}}
                </div>
                <button (click)="update()">set value to '1'</button>
            `,
            providers: [Service]
        })
        export class Component1 {
            subscription;
            value: string;
            constructor(private service: Service) {
                this.headerStateSubscription = this.service.getObservable().subscribe(value => {
                    this.value = value;
                });
            }
            update() {
                this.service.setValue('1')
            }
        }
```

Component 2

```
        @Component({
            selector: 'comp-2',
            template: `
                <div>
                Value in component 2: {{value}}
                </div>
                <button (click)="update()">set value to '2'</button>
            `,
            providers: [Service]
        })
        export class Component2 {
            subscription;
            value: string;
            constructor(private service: Service) {
                this.headerStateSubscription = this.service.getObservable().subscribe(value => {
                    this.value = value;
                });
            }
            update() {
                this.service.setValue('2')
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use singleton service instead of individual instance for each of component. So remove

```
providers: [Service]
```

from components metadata and add it to `AppModule` or common parent component

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/0VTIan11UPEnTuImzeML?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 components have a far better way of notifying parent/child components that something has changed, via events. There’s no longer two-way data binding in Angular in the same way we knew it in AngularJS, it’s designed around a uni-directional data flow system that adopts a much more reasonable approach to application development.

In bigger or more complex application is better to use redux pattern.

[Angular2 Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html)

[StackOverflow - What is the proper use of an EventEmitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter)

[Build a Better Angular 2 Application with Redux and ngrx](http://onehungrymind.com/build-better-angular-2-application-redux-ngrx/)

Answer (score 0):

I have Updated your plunker for it to work

link - https://plnkr.co/edit/grcuPBYTiDNRfo26UVbB?p=preview

changed service and providers

```
 value: string;

  subject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {  }

  setValue(value: string): void {
    this.value = value;
    this.subject.next(this.value);
  }

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [
    App,
    Component1,
    Component2
  ],
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  providers:[Service]
})
```

But ngrx is the better approach for you to prevent spaghetti code

This a classic case of using ngrx or the redux pattern

Please check this link for Angular Ngrx Example.

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts

-> Advanced Concept -> ngrx store