# Emitting events globally

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What am trying to achieve is I would like to emit a custom event in angular2 globally and have multiple components listen to it so not just the parent-child pattern

In my event source component, I have

```
export class EventSourceComponent{

  @Output() testev = new EventEmitter();

  onbtnclick(){
    this.testev.emit("i have emitted an event")
  }
 }
```

Now I would like other components to get this event

```
export class CmpTwoComponent{

    //here get the emitted event with data
  }
```

How do I achieve the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a shared service for that.

```
export class EventSourceComponent{
    constructor(private sharedService : SharedService){}


      onbtnclick(){
        this.sharedService.testev.next("i have emitted an event")
      }
 }

export class CmpTwoComponent{

//here get the emitted event with data

   constructor(sharedService : SharedService){

      sharedService.testev.subscribe((event)=>{console.log(event)})
   }

}
```

and then the sharedService would be

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService{

   public testev = new Subject()

}
```

Obviously, if you still need the `Output` so the parent component could be able to subscribe normally, you could add that too :

```
export class EventSourceComponent{

    @Output() testev = new EventEmitter();
    constructor(private sharedService : SharedService){}


      onbtnclick(){
        this.testev.emit("i have emitted an event")
        this.sharedService.testev.next("i have emitted an event")
      }
 }
```

Comment: You should not use `EventEmitter` inside your services; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter. Use an `Observable`/`Subject` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pattern in Angular that allows to achieve what you ask for.

The best option that I can think of for you would be to create a custom service. Make some service that you inject into AppComponent (therefore having a single instance of the service). In the Service you can have whatever logic you want.

Comment: For global events in angular 2, you may want to look  at this: https://modewagon.wordpress.com/2017/09/12/angular2-4-global-events/  might help