# Angular2 materialize dropdown EventEmitter with no unsubscribe

Tags: angular

I peeped into materialize dropdown code

and in the service folder (ng2-dropdown-state.ts) I can see the use

of EventEmitter but in the component folder I can't see any unsubscribe on

the ngOnDestroy hook.

So I'm wondering if could be memory leak problem.

May be I'm wrong but I'd like to know is or not

in any part of the code there was a way to avoid the

memory leak problem.

Can someone explain me, please ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to unofficial [ng2-material-dropdown](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ng2-material-dropdown/blob/master/src/modules/services/ng2-dropdown-state.ts) - afaik yes, there is possibility of memory leak, because the RxJS `Subject` (that `EventEmitter` extends) is subscribed to [here](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ng2-material-dropdown/blob/78f30347b00baff901ac2aaa0896cfbce1c69460/src/modules/components/dropdown/ng2-dropdown.ts#L75) and never unsubscribed. Also as an `EventEmitter` it cannot be finished - that's why [it shouldn't be subscribed manually to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter), they are intended to be used in Angular's `@Output()` only.

Good you've seen that, so you can choose better library or make a pull request to this one.

Comment: I know that but there is no unsubscribe of the EventEmitter in the code for this the question

Comment: Right, I've changed the answer to be on topic