# Angular data binding

Tags: angular, typescript

In the following code, how can I make the `orderItems` auto refresh after I call `addOrderItem()`? Currently I have to call `this.service.getOrderItems()` again to manually refresh it.

```
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
    orderItems: OrderItem[];
    ...
    ngOnInit() {
        ...
        this.orderItems = this.service.getOrderItems();
    }
    addOrderItem(): void {
        this.service.addOrderItem();
    }
}
```

Comment: adding an item to a data bound array should already auto refresh without you needing to do anything

Comment: @pixelbits The order items array is returned by the service which I think is a deep copy of the original array. When I call the service to add things to the original array, this deep copy does not refresh but the original array does.

Comment: Ah,I understand they are different arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encapsulated your `addOrderItem()` service method so you can call `getOrderItems` in this encapsulation so it will be refreshed each time you add an OrderItem:

```
addOrderItem(): void {
  this.service.addOrderItem();
  this.orderItems = this.service.getOrderItems();
}
```

You can also [subscribe to an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351598/angular-4-emitting-and-subscribing-to-an-event-in-a-shared-service?rq=1) from your service to call a function each time `addOrderItem()` is called.