# angular 2: using a service to broadcast an event

Tags: angular, service, eventemitter

I'm trying to get a button click in one component to put focus on an element on another component. (Frankly, I don't understand why this must be so complex, but I have not been able to implement any simpler way that actually works.)

I'm using a service. It doesn't need to pass any data except *that* the click occurred. I'm not sure how the listening component is meant to respond to the event.

app.component:

Skip to main content

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SkipToContentService } from './services/skip-to-content.service';


export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
        private skipToContent: SkipToContentService
    ) {}
    }

    skipLink() {
        this.skipToContent.setClicked();
    }

}
```

login component:

```
<input type="text" name="username" />


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SkipToContentService } from '../../../services/skip-to-content.service';

export class BaseLoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private skipToContent: SkipToContentService
        ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.skipToContent.skipClicked.subscribe(
            console.log("!")
            // should put focus() on input
        );

    }
}
```

skip-to-content.service:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SkipToContentService {

    skipClicked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();


    constructor() {
    }

    setClicked() {
        console.log('clicked');
        this.skipClicked.emit();
    };
}
```

I'm  a bit lost here as to how logon will "hear" the skipClicked event.

Comment: You shouldn't use `EventEmitter` in your services https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter. And use a shared service for broadcasting events: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of `EventEmitter`. Change the declaration of `skipCliekd` to the following:

```
skipClicked: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

Then, you need to broadcast the new value using `next()` method as following:

```
this.skipClicked.next (true);
```

Also, change your subscription to:

```
 this.skipToContent.skipClicked.subscribe( value => {
     if (value === true) {
         console.log("!"); 
         // should put focus() on input 
     }
 });
```

Comment: A few problems: 1] "generatorOrNext is not a function" at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (event_emitter.ts:115)
2] the event is fired automatically on pageload. i.e. first thing I get is '! '.
3] As far as I can tell, next() is deprecated in favor of emit()

Comment: EventEmmiter, that only used in a component

Comment: EventEmitter should only be used in an actual component, Angular component integration guideline recommends using shared service as in another answer, thus downvoting because answer need update or misleading others

Answer (score 17):

#### EventEmitter should only be used in an actual component with an @Output directive. Anything else may not work in future.

For child-parent communication it is better to use a Subject or BehaviorSubject. This is an example from the angular guide.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

```
@Injectable()
export class MissionService {

  // Observable string sources
  private missionAnnouncedSource = new Subject<string>();
  private missionConfirmedSource = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable string streams
  missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
  missionConfirmed$ = this.missionConfirmedSource.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  announceMission(mission: string) {
    this.missionAnnouncedSource.next(mission);
  }

  confirmMission(astronaut: string) {
    this.missionConfirmedSource.next(astronaut);
  }
}
```

---

#### Tip:

If you have an event that just signifies something has occurred or completed - and has no actual data associated with it - you can use a `Subject<void>()`. This makes the signature of `next()` cleaner and you don't need to provide a dummy value for the sake of it.

Eg.

```
windowClosed = new Subject<void>();
```

`windowClosed.next()` will emit the event

Comment: And yes I'm really having a hard time too when I just need the service to do ONE thing. And what do I even name it? Is it named for the component, or named for the action or named for the type of action. I guess you just have to see what works for you.

Comment: Another key thing to remember is you can composite services that you're using for internal data transfer. They can inject into each other, and you can inject 5 services you want if you had a complex control with 5 unrelated children. I wish they had a better name than 'service'