# ObjectUnsubscribedError after timeout

Tags: angular

I am using an Event EventEmitter in a service component like this:

```js
export class SettingsService {
    public sidebarColor = '#D80B0B';
    public sidebarColorUpdate: EventEmitter<string> = new >EventEmitter();
```

I then subscribe to it from other components like this :

```js
this.settingsService.sidebarColorUpdate.subscribe((color: string) => {
    if (color === '#fff') {
        this.normalFontColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,.6)';
        this.dividerBgColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,.1)';
    } else {
        this.normalFontColor = 'rgba(255,255,255,.8)';
        this.dividerBgColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)';
    }
 });
```

And then unsubscribe in the `ngOnDestroy`. This works great but the problem now arises when the session times out and the router defaults back to the login page. After login in again I get this error

> message: "object unsubscribed" name: "ObjectUnsubscribedError"

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell why do you get this error but that's not the major problem here. The issue is that you **should not be using EventEmitter in the services** because [it does not guarantee to remain Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076701/1199711).

Here is a proper solution to your problem using Observables:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class SettingsService {
    // Source variable should be private to prevent subscribing to it
    private sidebarColorUpdatedSource = new Subject<string>();
    // Expose an observable to allow subscribers listen to the updates
    sidebarColorUpdated$ = this.sidebarColorUpdatedSource.asObservable();

    // Expose a public method for updating the sidebar color
    updateSidebarColor(color: string): void {
        // Update the color

        // Notify subscribers
        this.sidebarColorUpdatedSource.next(color);
    }
}
```

Component:

```js
private sidebarColorUpdated$: Subscription;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sidebarColorUpdated$ = this.settingsService.sidebarColorUpdated$.subscribe(color => {
        // Do whatever you need
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.sidebarColorUpdated$)
        this.sidebarColorUpdated$.unsubscribe();
}
```

When you need to update the sidebar color call `SettingsService.updateSidebarColor(color: string)` method and each subscriber will be notified of the change.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will give that a go now.