# Default Value for Event Emitter

Tags: angular, eventemitter

Suppose I have some event that emits a string value from a service:

`public myString: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();`

And then in my component, I emit it as follows:

`this.myService.myString.emit(value)`

I want to set a default value for the string that consumes this event when no event has yet to be emitted. Is it possible to do something like:

```
public setString: string = 'Default Value, No Emission Yet' || this.myService.subscribe(emittedValue => this.setString = emittedValue);
```

Comment: But inorder to consume the event you have to emit it right? so u can assign the value at the time event emits

Comment: You can just have `public setString = 'Default Value, No Emission Yet'` and then subscribe to the emissions in `ngOnInit` or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using a service, I would recommend not to use `EventEmitter`: [What is the proper use of an EventEmitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter)

Since you want an initial value, I would suggest a `BehaviorSubject` that takes an initial value.

```ts
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

private myString = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Default Value, No Emission Yet')
public myString$ = this.myString.asObsevable();
```

Then just in your component you can listen to this observable and perform actions accordingly. Remember to unsubscribe when component is destroyed!

```ts
mySub = new Subscription();

constructor(private myService: MyService) { 
  this.mySub = myService.myString$.subscribe(value => {
    // conditions and do stuff...
  })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.mySub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I just used this now and it worked perfectly! Thanks