# Angular 2: How to Test Subscribing to an Event Emitter in an Entry (Imperative) Component?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, observable, eventemitter

It may be that my components just aren't structured correctly, although they work as needed when running the app; I just can't get my test to pass.

**Parent component** (I'm using an ng-bootstrap modal; this function is called on a button click):

```
  openMyModal() {
    this.myModalRef = this._modalService.open(ExtractModalComponent); //this is what ng-bootstrap prescribes for opening their modals
    this.myModalRef.componentInstance.setRangeRequest.subscribe($e => {  
      this.setDateRange($e.fromDate, $e.toDate); //<== I'm trying to test that this is called
    });
```

**child component has this output:**

```
@Output() setRangeRequest = new EventEmitter()
...
clickHandler() {
  this.setRangeRequest.emit({ fromDate: this.fromDateTime, toDate: this.toDateTime });
}
```

And below is my **parent component spec**. I'm not sure if I've created the spy correct, and though the order of the *act* step seems right to me (code that subscribes to the observable, followed by emitting the event that was subscribed to), the test fails with `cannot read property fromDate of undefined` and if I switch those statements, and emit first, then the test fails with `expected spy to be called with... but was never called`.

```
it('should use dates returned from the modal in the service call', fakeAsync(() =>{
    //Arrange
    let dt = moment(new Date()).format();
    let modalSpy = spyOn(comp.myModalRef.componentInstance, 'setRangeRequest').and.returnValue(
      Observable.of({ fromDate: dt, toDate: dt })
    );

    //Act
    comp.openMyModal
    comp.myModalRef.componentInstance.downloadRequest.emit();
    tick();

    //Assert
    expect(eduExtractDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(comp.workingFile.loadId, dt, dt);
  })
);
```

Comment: just found this answer, but it's from such a long time ago, don't know if its directions to never subscribe to an event emitter are still valid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter

Comment: But as that post was made about a pre-release version of Angular 2, this seems to be more relevant now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47167133/3406483. Doesn't solve the problem in question, but at least indicates I'm not completely wrong in trying to subscribe to the event emitter.