# RxJS fromEvent operator with output EventEmitter in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

Say there's `ChildComponent` which emits out an event called `someEvent`. Obviously, I can catch the event in `ParentComponent` declaring like, `<child-component (someEvent)="onSomeEvent($event)"></child-component>` and handle it with the method `onSomeEvent` in `ParentComponent`. But what I'm trying is that I want to handle the event with `fromEvent` operator in RxJS. I've tried `fromEvent(this.childComponent.nativeElement, 'someEvent')` after getting the `ElementRef` of the `ChildComponent` with `@ViewChild`. I discovered that the above approach works if the output EventEmitter's event name is the same as one of the native events such as `click` but it doesn't respond/work otherwise. Is there any ways to make it work with `fromEvent`?

Comment: Why do you want to use `fromEvent`? Are you trying to convert the Angular event into an observable?

Comment: @cartant Actually, using `fromEvent` is not that necessary but I'm trying to approach this way to handle the flow with rxjs operators

Comment: @cartant Would you mind reposting your answer? I was confused. It's still not working.

Comment: I've undeleted the answer. There are good reasons for avoiding direct access to native elements in Angular and for [not treating event emitters as observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter).

Comment: @cartant I think Accessing native elements directly in Angular is not bad unless I manipulate it. Why is it bad?

Comment: I find the original answer interresting: *I discovered that the above approach works if the output EventEmitter's event name is the same as one of the native events such as `click` but it doesn't work otherwise*. Is it possible to use `fromEvent(..,'customClick')` for custom events fired from `EventEmitter`? Lets say one directive on the same element fires `customClick` and second directive on the same element want to listen to such events. I solved it injecting one directive to the other and manually subscribe to `EventEmitter`, but I am curious why `fromEvent(..,'customClick')` doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to convert the event into an observable, you could use a `Subject`, like this:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    <child-component (someEvent)="subject.next($event)">
    </child-component>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  public subject = new Subject<any>();
  constructor() {
    this.subject.pipe(
      tap(event => console.log(event)) // or whatever
    ).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Doing so will provide you with an observable source - the subject - that emits whatever value the event emitter emits. From that you can compose whatever you want using RxJS operators.

Comment: So there will be no way to bind `Component` event(output EventEmitter) with `fromEvent` operator other than using `Subject`? With your suggestion, I would be able to use rxjs operators as I wanted but I would need to have seemingly extra `Subject` variable to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Even if you could, you shouldn't. cartant's solution is the correct one that you should use.

Comment: @IngoBürk Apparently, I could directly subscribe to `someEvent`. Why should I have an extra Subject for this?

Comment: @DongBinKim Because `EventEmitter` [is not guaranteed to be implemented as an observable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076701/6680611). It's being an observable is an implementation detail.