# Obseravables Service - Missunderstanding / Best Practise

Tags: angular, observable, angular-event-emitter

I'm struggling around with the observe service approach between two components. I have a profile component that includes a settings component. Both uses the user.service where the provider is defined within app.module.ts. The provider isn't defined any where else. So when I change as example the firstName over the settings.component and save it. The change won't get reflected within the profile.component sidebar until I reload the page.

**After hours:**
I found a solution to do that over an eventemitter that will be trigger as soon as the update occurs. This would solve my problem above but I think this isn't the right way to go since I read the article below:

[What is the proper use of an EventEmitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter)

Shouldn't it work without an event emmiter?

**So my question:** 
What approach would you use for that situation or what is the best practise? Of course there can be an issue within my code. I'm really new in angular.

**app.module.ts**

Within the app.module.ts i defined:

```
 providers: [UserService]
```

**profile.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile',
    templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    user: any;
    Role = Role;
    constructor(private _userService: UserService, ) { }


    ngOnInit() {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const role = jwt.decode(token).user.role;
        this._userService.getUser().subscribe(v => { this.user = v; });
        // Event Emmiter Subscription
        this._userService.change.subscribe(v => { this.user = v; });
    }
}
```

**profile.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="user" class="container mt50">
    <div class="row profile">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="profile-sidebar">
                <!-- SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
                <div class="profile-userpic">
                    <img gravatar [email]="user.email" [size]="256" class="img-responsive animated bounceIn" alt="">
                </div>
                <!-- END SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
                <!-- SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
                <div class="profile-usertitle">
                    <div class="profile-usertitle-name">
                        {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile-usertitle-job">
                        {{ user.email }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
                <app-profile-settings-admin *ngIf="user.role === Role.ADMINISTRATOR"></app-profile-settings-admin>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**user.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    public user: any;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    // EVENT EMIITER
    public change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    getUser() {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
            ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
            : '';
        return this.http.get('api/user' + token)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                this.user = response.json().obj;
                return this.user;
            })
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }

    updateUser(user) {
        const body = JSON.stringify(user);
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
            ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
            : '';
        return this.http.patch('api/user/' + token, body, {headers: headers})
            .map((response: Response) => {
                const result = response.json();
                this.user = result.obj;
                // EMIT EVENT
                this.change.emit(this.user);
                return this.user;
            })
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }
}
```

**profile.settings.admin.component.ts**

Within that component there is nothing more than a form that will fire the following code on submit:

```
onSubmit() {
    this._userService.updateUser(this.userForm.value)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this._toastyService.default('Settings saved!');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error =>{
                this._toastyService.default('Error occured!');
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: A best practice is to not use EventEmitter for that, this was explained in linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter . Use RxJS Subject instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ss1yj?file=app%2Fprofile.component.ts)
You do not need to fire an Event to share (and sync) data between components. Let Angular services (and Angular forms) to control that for you:

**Profile.component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const role = jwt.decodeToken(token).user.role;
    this._userService.getUser().subscribe(v => {
        this.user = v; 
    });
}
```

**user.service**

```
getUser() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        : '';
    return this.http.get('api/user' + token)
        .pipe(map((user: HttpResponse<any>) => {
            this.user = user;
                return this.user;
            }),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => Observable.throw(error)))
}

updateUser(user) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(user);
    const headers: HttpHeaders =  new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        : '';
    return this.http.patch('api/user/' + token, body, {headers})
        .pipe(map((user: HttpResponse<any>) => {
            this.user = user;
            return this.user;
        }),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => Observable.throw(error)));
}
```

**profile.settings.admin.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._userService.getUser().subscribe((user: User) => {
        this.user = user;         
    });
}

onSubmit() {
    this._userService.updateUser(this.user)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this._toastyService.default('Settings saved!');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error =>{
                this._toastyService.default('Error occured!');
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
}
```

**profile.settings.admin.component.html**

```
<form #userForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="nameHelp" 
            placeholder="enter name" [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name" required #name="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
            class="alert alert-danger">
            Name is required
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" aria-describedby="lastNameHelp" 
            placeholder="enter last name" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" name="lastName" required #lastName="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="lastName.valid || lastName.pristine"
            class="alert alert-danger">
            last Name is required
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
            placeholder="enter email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" required #email="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="email.valid || email.pristine"
            class="alert alert-danger">
            email is required
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onSubmit()" >Submit</button>
</form>
```