# Trigger function only when specific element is not null

Tags: angular

My page contains two components, parent and child.

In the child I am receiving data from the server, and I save this data in a service. I want to execute a function in the parent only when the data in the service is not null, because I am using this data in the parent function.

How can I be sure that the data is already in the service before I execute the function in the parent?

Of course I want to execute the function while the page loads, as soon as possible, and I prefer to not use setTimeout function.

For example:

```ts
//child
this.jsonService.getData().subscribe(res => {
  this.CommonService.userDetails = res;    
}
```

```ts
//service
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
public userDetails: any;
}
```

```ts
//parent

// execute only when the this.CommonService.userDetails != null
doSomething(){ 
 alert(this.CommonService.userDetails)
}
```

Comment: Expose an observable from the service that sends an event when the value of userDetails is set. Then the parent just subscribes to that.

Comment: i am not sure what do you mean. you can attach some code? thanks!

Comment: That's what the code in the answer already provided does. I'd recommend reading up on observables and RxJS, they're pretty central in Angular.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited answer:**
As stated by @jonrsharpe and in the documentation about [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service), it's better to use `Subject` rather than `EventEmitter`.

Here is the updated code for the service:

```
// Service
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
    private userDetailsReceivedSource = new Subject<any>();

    userDetailsReceived$ = this.userDetailsReceivedSource.asObservable();

    private userDetailsData: any;

    receiveUserDetails(data: any) {
        this.userDetailsData = data;
        this.userDetailsReceivedSource.next(data);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the child component using `receiveUserDetails`:

```
// Child
this.jsonService.getData().subscribe(res => {
    this.CommonService.receiveUserDetails(res);    
}
```

Here is the updated code for the parent component using `userDetailsReceived$`:

```
// Parent
constructor() {
    this.CommonService.userDetailsReceived$.subscribe(_ => this.doSomething());
}
```

**Original answer:**

In the service, you will need an `EventEmitter` to notify the parent component when the data is available.

The `setter` is used to `emit` the event when we receive the data from the child component.

```
// Service
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
    public onUserDetailsReceived = new EventEmitter<any>();

    private userDetailsData: any;

    public get userDetails(): any {
        return this.userDetailsData
    }

    public set userDetails(data: any) {
        this.userDetailsData = data;
        onUserDetailsReceived.emit();
    }
}
```

In the parent component, you will have to subscribe to the `EventEmitter` to be notified.

```
// Parent
constructor() {
    this.CommonService.onUserDetailsReceived.subscribe(_ => this.doSomething());
}
```

Comment: are you sure about this syntax?  "public get userDetails" it's not compile for me. And I did not quite understand, how the userDetails refer to the  EventEmitter. thanks you!

Comment: @levi Sorry, some parenthesis was missing: answer edited.

Comment: You shouldn't use EventEmitters for purposes other than component @Outputs; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter#36076701. Use a proper subject/observable instead, if you aren't sure how I've written about it e.g. here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated the answer.