# send EventEmitter from child component to parent component in ngBootstrap

Tags: angular, angular7, ng-bootstrap

I want to pass a modal event from the child component to the modal's parent component, but i got an error " modalRf.componentInstance.confirmationEvent is not a function"

child Component: ModalTestComponent.ts

```js
@Input() idModal: string;

@Input() titre: string;

@Input() message: string;

@Output() confirmationEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
}

public confirmer() {
   this.confirmationEvent.emit();
}
```

Parent Component

```js
openActiviteModal() {
   const modalRf = this.modalService.open(ModalTestComponent, 'TestModalId');
   modalRf.componentInstance.titre = 'HELLO WORLD';
   modalRf.componentInstance.message = 'THANKS';
   modalRf.componentInstance.confirmationEvent().subscribe(
       res => {
           if (res && res !== '' && res !== undefined) {
               this.afterConfirmChangementActivite();
           }
       }
   );
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the selector of the child component ?

Comment: of course : it's 'modal-test'

Comment: Didn't you add your `confirmationEvent` within selector ? eg: `<modal-test (confirmationEvent) = " "> `

Comment: no i didn't add **confirmationEvent** within selector

Comment: Better to go through in [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) link to understand @Output.

Comment: thanks  Denuka Nirmalee

Comment: did it work b.geeker ?

Comment: no it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact it is better to add the `confirmationEvent`in the selector (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter)), I think you can simply fix your code by removing the parenthesis after `modalRf.componentInstance.confirmationEvent`

```
modalRf.componentInstance.confirmationEvent.subscribe(
   res => {
       if (res && res !== '' && res !== undefined) {
           this.afterConfirmChangementActivite();
       }
   }
);
```