# With RXJS, can I have an observable or subject connected to an ever changing source observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Specific application:

In an Angular (6) component, I have a `FormGroup` with a `valueChanges object of type observable` that needs to be directed to an `EventEmitter`. If this `FormGroup` were never changing, its `valueChanges` could be the `EventEmitter`, but the `FormGroup` changes (reassigned) in response to a changing combobox.

The `FormGroup` represents an array of checkboxes.

The `EventEmitter` is `EventEmitter<{ [code: string]: boolean }>`.

Presently what is happening is:

```
this._myFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.myEventEmitter.emit(value));
```

Because the group is reassigned, and so I don't want to lose any subscriptions on the output event emitter.

EDIT: To clear up exactly what I am hoping for:

I would like a way to have as part of the public interface an `@Output() myEventEmitter` that is the same instance always (thus maintains subscriptions).

With a form group that changes (note: it is dynamically generated for each change of the combobox) but can feed in its observable into `myEventEmitter` without having to call emit in a subscribe which some view as a bad practice.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can use the form group in a different form without having to subscribe again.

Comment: @dmcgrandle it was in the title, but added some detail at the end just in case.

Comment: @Reactgular the form (on the template) is regenerated and the form group is reassigned to the new options needed. There are no other forms.

Comment: I have a question - are you saying that every time the _myFormGroup is reassigned, then you re-subscribe as well (with the code you showed), which then updates the eventEmitter with the new value?

Comment: @dmcgrandle yes (with associated unsubscribe)

Comment: Ok then, why not just emit valueChanges?  Every time a new one is created, emit it with `this.myEventEmitter.emit(this._myFormGroup.valueChanges)`.  This makes your eventEmitter into an observable of observables (higher order), and each inner observable can have multiple values, complete, etc.  Your subscriptions on the event emitter will need to be refactored to cope with a higher order Observable.  BTW: subscriptions on eventEmitters are also bad practice, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076701/8105437) for why...

Comment: @dmcgrandle I do want to be able to use as a normal event emitter generally, there are presently no subscriptions on it. But I have looked at that page and see the general arguments.

I don't want to have the event emitter being a higher order observable because it seems like a weird interface to provide the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with the form group when you could have an event on the template wired up to an event emitter?

```
<input *ngFor="let value in values; index as i" type="checkbox"
  [checked]="values[i]" (click)="values[i] = !values[i];emit(values)">
```

and in your component

```
emit => val => { myEventEmitter.emit(val); }
```

Comment: There are *n* checkboxes contained in the form group.