# Data binding with not nested components

Tags: angular

I have some component with checkboxes. And I have another component with table. The components are not one inside another. When I uncheck checkbox I need to change classes to some table columns on table component. What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076701/6478359

Comment: Is there a common parent component template where both the children components are used?

Comment: @MichaelD, the standard root app.component

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL, what is the good way if it is not paren->child structure in my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular most of the communication happens in the following ways.

1. PARENT -> CHILD , use Input EventEmitter.
2. CHILD -> PARENT, use Output EventEmitter.
3. If no immediate relation between components -> Use a Data Service, angular service which both the components are dependent on to publish and retrieve data.
4. Also you can use the ViewChild, if your child component is housed inside the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, both the components are used in app.component.html. Then you can create an event emitter for the `change` event in the check-box component. And in the app.component.html, assign a template variable to table component and assign any of it's function directly as callback for checkbox component's emitted event. Try the following

checkbox.component.html

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1" (change)="change.emit($event)"> Checkbox
```

checkbox.component.ts

```js
@Output change = new EventEmitter();
```

app.component.html

```html
<app-checkbox (change)="table1.checkboxChange($event)"></app-checkbox>
<app-table #table1></app-table>
```

table.component.ts

```js
checkboxChange(event: any) {
  // change CSS selector of element
}
```

One advantage of this method is the parent component remains untouched and so an additional rerouting is avoided.