# Emit an event From services Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components, angular-event-emitter

Componet Code

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { CommonService } from 'src/app/services/common.service';
import { FormioService } from 'src/app/services/formio.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-initialrecord',
  templateUrl: './initialrecord.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./initialrecord.component.sass']
})
export class InitialRecordComponent implements OnInit {
  form: any = "";
  rendered = false;
  showForm: any = false;
  showTable: any = false;
  showAdd: any = true;
  showClose: any = false;
  patientData: any = {};
  currentTab = "";
  submitFunction = 'onSubmit';
  formId: any = ''
  rows: any = [];
  cols: any = [];
  formioJson: any;
  patientid = "";
  patientName = ""
  @Output() refreshForm = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() patientDetails: any = {};
  constructor(
    private FormioService: FormioService,
    private commonService: CommonService,
    private socket: Socket ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.patientid=JSON.parse(this.commonService.getValue("patientDetails"))._id
    this.patientName =JSON.parse(this.commonService.getValue("patientDetails")).data.fname
    this.formioJson = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("formioJson"));
    this.listFormData('vitals')
  }

  listFormData(formName: string) {
    this.formId = formName;
    this.rows = [];
    this.cols = []
    this.toggleView(true, false, true, false)
    this.currentTab = this.formioJson[formName].name;
    let path = this.formioJson[formName].path
    let fromName = this.formioJson[formName].name
    this.FormioService.loadForms(path).subscribe(data => {
      this.FormioService.checkNested(data, true);
      this.cols = this.FormioService.cols;
    })
//calling service function
    this.FormioService.getFormData(path, formName, this.patientid, "data.patientId")
// subscribe the event
    this.FormioService.receivedRow.subscribe((param: any) => {
      this.rows = param.row;
      this.patientData[this.formioJson[formName].name] = param.data;
    });
  }

}
```

service code

```
import { Injectable , EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonService } from 'src/app/services/common.service';
import  moment from 'moment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormioService {
  headers: any;
  row :any[];
  cols:any[];
  receivedRow: EventEmitter<any>;
  patientData: any ={};
  constructor(private socket: Socket, private toaster: ToastrService,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,private commonService: CommonService) {
      this.receivedRow = new EventEmitter<any>()
      this.headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8','x-jwt-token':this.commonService.getValue("formioToken")})
     }
  public FORMIO_BASE_URL = environment.formioBaseUrl;
  public SOCKET_IO_URL = environment.nodeServerUrl


  getFormData(formUrl: string, tabName: string, patientId: string,keyName:string) {
    let form: any = new Object();
    form.roomId = this.commonService.roomId();
    form.token = this.commonService.getToken();
    form.eventName = tabName;
    form.formId = formUrl;
    form.query = keyName+"=" + patientId
    this.socket.emit('list', form);
    this.socket.on(tabName, async data => {
      this.row=[]
      data.forEach(element => {
        element.data['date'] =moment(element.created).format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm');
        console.log( element.data['date'] =moment(element.created).format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm'))
        this.row.push(element.data);
      });
      this.receivedRow.emit({row:this.row,data:data})
      console.log(this.row,"Formioservice")
    });
  }
  checkNested(obj: any,flag) {
    if(flag){
      this.cols =[]
      this.cols.push(JSON.parse( '{"field":"date","header":"Date"}'))
    }
    for (let prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] == "object") {
          //console.log('Key: ${prop}')
          this.checkNested(obj[prop],false);
        } else {
          //console.log("key >>> " + key + " >> props >>> " + obj[prop]);
          if (obj['tableView']) {
            //  console.log(`Key: ${prop} 'key_value: ${obj['key']} 'label_value: ${obj['label']} 'table_view_value: ${obj['tableView']} `)
            let temp: string = '{"field":"' + obj['key'] + '","header":"' + this.capitalize(obj['label']) + '"}';
            //  console.log(JSON.parse(temp));
            this.cols.push(JSON.parse(temp));
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }
  capitalize = (s: any) => {
    if (typeof s !== 'string') return ''
    return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
  }
}
```

[on reading this link able to know its not good practice to use eventemitter in servies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter) .The above code working perfectly my issue is I have common function for formData which fetch value of form depend on tabclick value.1st time event is emitting as expect when click other tab i.e second click its emitting two time,when third time its emitting 3 times 4 means 4 times can any one suggest me the best approach I am ne to angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initiating a new subscription each time the `listFormData` function is called. Instead you could subscribe in the `ngOnInit()` hook once.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.patientid=JSON.parse(this.commonService.getValue("patientDetails"))._id
  this.patientName =JSON.parse(this.commonService.getValue("patientDetails")).data.fname
  this.formioJson = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("formioJson"));
  this.listFormData('vitals')
  // subscribe the event
  this.FormioService.receivedRow.subscribe((param: any) => {
    this.rows = param.row;
    this.patientData[this.formioJson[formName].name] = param.data;
  });
}

listFormData(formName: string) {
  this.formId = formName;
  this.rows = [];
  this.cols = []
  this.toggleView(true, false, true, false)
  this.currentTab = this.formioJson[formName].name;
  let path = this.formioJson[formName].path
  let fromName = this.formioJson[formName].name
  this.FormioService.loadForms(path).subscribe(data => {
    this.FormioService.checkNested(data, true);
    this.cols = this.FormioService.cols;
  });
  //calling service function
  this.FormioService.getFormData(path, formName, this.patientid, "data.patientId");
}
```

---

Also like you've mentioned in the question, `EventEmitter` is not designed as an Angular specific implementation of a multicast observable. It's purpose is to provide custom events to components with parent-child relationships.

If you look at the source of the [`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L64), it is an interface extension of the RxJS [`Subject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject). So if we require a multicast observable in a service, we could use it directly.

Service

```js
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FormioService {
  ...
  receivedRowSource = new Subject<any>();
  receivedRow$ = this.receivedRowSource.asObservable();

  getFormData(formUrl: string, tabName: string, patientId: string,keyName:string) {
    ...
    this.socket.on(tabName, async data => {
      ...
      this.receivedRowSource.next({row:this.row,data:data});       // <-- use `next` to push new notification
    });
  }
}
```

You also need to close any active subscriptions upon closing of the component to avoid potential memory leaks. You could either call assign the subscription to a member variable an call `unsubscribe()` in the `ngOnDestroy()` hook or use RxJS `takeUntil()` operator.

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class InitialRecordComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  ...
  completed$ = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.FormioService.receivedRow$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.completed$)        // <-- pipe in the `takeUntil()` here
    ).subscribe((param: any) => {
      this.rows = param.row;
      this.patientData[this.formioJson[formName].name] = param.data;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.completed$.next();
    this.completed$.complete();
  }
}
```