# Angular Unit - Testing how to subscribe event emitter

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular11

In my unit test I want to call `openDialog`, `openPdf`, `getPath` with these three eventemitter that are in the `ngOnDestroy` method. How can I call them?

`component.ts`:

```js
pdfPath: string = ''; // will be edited later

@Output() openDialog = new EventEmitter();
@Output() openPdf = new EventEmitter();
@Output() getPath: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
 
getData() {
  // ...
  this.openDialog.emit(true);
}

showData() {
  // ...
  this.openPdf.emit();
}

fetchData() {
  // ...
  this.getPath.emit(this.pdfPath);
}


ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.openDialog.unsubscribe();
    this.openPdf.unsubscribe();
    this.getPath.unsubscribe();
}
```

I've tried calling them like this in the `beforeEach` and use   spyOn(component.openDialog, 'subscribe');
, but this isn't working:

```
const emitter = new EventEmitter();
component.openDialog = emitter;
component.openPdf = emitter;
component.getPath = emitter;
emitter.emit(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your problem correctly.

If you want to check if the `emit` function was called, then you can check this with a spy:

```js
it('#getData should emit openDialog', () => {
  const emitSpy = spyOn(component.openDialog, 'emit');

  component.getData();

  expect(emitSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // checks if `openDialog.emit()` has been called
  expect(emitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true); // checks if `openDialog.emit()` has been called with `true`
});
```

For more information about spies, just search for "[Jasmine Spies](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy.html)".

If you simply use the `emit()` function in a unit test then you can do that with the automatically generated `component` variable:

```js
describe('BookShelfComponent', () => {
  let component: BookShelfComponent; // your component
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BookShelfComponent>;

  // ...

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BookShelfComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('#openDialog.emit should emit openDialog', () => {
    const emitSpy = spyOn(component.openDialog, 'emit');

    component.openDialog.emit(); // call `emit()`

    expect(emitSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // only for the demonstration that `emit()` was executed
  });
});
```

If that didn't answer your question, try again to describe your problem more clearly.

Another anomaly in your code is your `ngOnDestroy()`. You call `unsubscribe()` to your `EventEmitter`, which you shouldn't do. Because EventEmitters [should only be used to emit events from components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter), and hence they should not be subscribed to, there is no need to unsubscribe.
If you need to subscribe to it, you should rather use a [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) and not an EventEmitter with `@Output`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but issue are still there. when I run unit test case I am facing "Unhandled promise rejection: ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed" error.  if I commented code that is written in ngOnDestroyed method  then I am not facing any error, to solve this error I think I need to subscribe eventemitter in spec file. so how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I updated code snippet.

Comment: Oh yeah. You have to use the `unsubscribe()` method on a Subscription and not on EventEmitter. So you can remove the content of your `ngOnDestroy()`, because you [should not and dont't have to subscribe/unsubscribe EventEmitter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076701/9740071).

Comment: can you please tell me ,how can I dispatch Event for Eventemitter?

Comment: For @Output and EventEmitter have a look at: [Angular - Sharing data between child and parent directives and components](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)